# Error when i try my Logo Quiz like app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Everyone heard about Logo Quiz! I try to develop a game like logo quiz and this is the activity in which you have to put the name of the logo! The image and the name is received by intent . The image tag contains the name .

```
public class Vie extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView img;
    EditText et;
    Button btn;
    TextView txt;
    MediaPlayer win_sound, wrong_sound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vie);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

        win_sound = MediaPlayer.create(Vie.this, R.raw.win);
        wrong_sound= MediaPlayer.create(Vie.this, R.raw.wrong);

        setImageAndTagByIntent(img);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean mb = check(et, btn, img);
        if (mb = true) {
            // Sunet toast thread
            txt.setText(title(img));
            win_sound.start();

            Thread t = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.run();
                    try {
                        sleep(win_sound.getDuration());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        finish();
                    }

                }

            };

            t.start();

        }

        if (mb = false) {
            // sunet toast thread
            wrong_sound.start();
            Toast t = new Toast(Vie.this);
            t.setText("Wrong answer! Please check if you have spelled corectly the name of the team!");
            t.show();
        }
    }

    private CharSequence title(ImageView img2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = (String) img2.getTag();
        return s;
    }

    private void setImageAndTagByIntent(ImageView img2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Trece si tagul!
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bitmap back = i.getParcelableExtra("back");
        Drawable b = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), back);
        img2.setImageDrawable(b);
        String tag = i.getStringExtra("tag");
        Object tag2 = (Object) tag;
        img2.setTag(tag2);

    }

    private boolean check(EditText et2, Button btn2, ImageView img2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = et2.getText().toString();
        s = WordUtils.capitalize(s);
        String s1 = (String) img2.getTag();
        boolean b = false;

        if (hasBlank(s1) == true && s.contentEquals(firstWord(s1))) {
            b = true;
        }

        if (hasBlank(s1) == true && s.contentEquals(lastWord(s1))) {
            b = true;
        }

        if (s.contentEquals(s1) && hasBlank(s1) == false) {
            b = true;
        }

        return b;

    }

    private String lastWord(String s1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String arr[] = s1.split("//s");
        return arr[1];
    }

    private String firstWord(String s1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String arr[] = s1.split("//s");
        return arr[0];
    }

    private boolean hasBlank(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (string.contains(" ")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

But when I write anything in the edit text it appers as correct! Please Help Me! I think it is a problem with the boolean methode!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statements are wrong. In the onClick method you use only '=' instead of '=='. The equals sign assigns `true` to the value of `mb` and then the `if` is evaluated. This means that the value of mb is always set to true and thus every answer is evaluated as correct.

You should check like this:

```
if (mb == true) { ... }
```

or better yet

```
if (mb) { ... }
```

The same goes for checking false. You could use:

```
if (mb == false) { ... }
```

or

```
if (!mb) { ... }
```

Comment: ok that worked but when i pu something wrong in the edit text the toast doesnt appear and the app crashes

Comment: Hmm, that is a different question now. Can you may be post the stack trace from Log Cat. My guess is that something is wrong with the sound  implementation. However, I cannot help without more info. Also your question was related to the boolean check and not the crash error, so consider accepting the answer anyway